# Is there a way that I can autopopulate my webpage with pictures from another website?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple website (think of it as wikipedia without the text), where the users click links to people's names and then go to that person's personal page. I would like to be able to have an image of the person also show up on the personal page, but I don't want to hard code the links to the images or save them on my computer.

Is there a way that I can get the top search result from Google images and then copy that link to put into each page dynamically?

Comment: My first thought - The problem with doing something like this with JavaScript is that you would run into problems with Cross Domain scripting permissions issues at the client. You would have better luck coding it in PHP or .NET so that the server makes the call to the website holding the images. Then you have to parse the html and search for graphic file types.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide#introduction

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the google api ([Google image search api](http://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide#introduction) ), pull a search on page load for the user, parse the json for the "unescapedUrl" and use that as your img src attribute.